# Dynamics V9 on premise prod restore on dev environment

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I have a prod environment where the version of dynamics in 9.0.16.7 (prod, was not installed by me).

I have installed installed the new organization which is version 9.0.2.3034. (I have not applied any kind of updates, it was this version from the beginning).

Now I want to take all that's in prod to my new organization.

Steps I have performed:

- Got the backup of the prod environment sql database.
- Restored it in the sql of the dev server.
- Opened Deployment manager -> Import organization -> DB was automatically detected -> did the mapping -> waited for the result.

The result I got looks like this:

Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Database having version 9.0.16.7 is not supported for upgraded.

My question(s):

How can I restore the prod environment in my new organization ?

If I need to change the version of the new organization what are the steps that I need to take in order to achieve the result ?

Any kind of response will be awesome because I struggle finding any kind of resources about this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/service-update-0-16-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-9-0-f827ee5a-b67c-2629-502a-fa74dec29298) which upgraded the organization.

I imported organization and it succeeded.